# Disprove a set is not path connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $S=\left\{a,b,c \right\}$ and $\tau$ be the topoplogy on $S$ given by 
$$\tau = \{ \phi, \left\{b\right\},\left\{a,b\right\},\left\{b,c\right\}, \{ a, b, c\}\}.$$ 
Is this topological space path connected?

I can prove that this is a connected set. I think every continuous map from closed interval to  $S$ should be constant map.But I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping

$$ \gamma(x) = \begin{cases} a  &\text{if } x=0 \\ b & \text{if } x\in (0,1]\end{cases}$$

is continuous (check) and connects $a, b$. You can similar find a curve connecting other points. The space is path connected.